# PHP - Why can't I insert information into my table?

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert information into my table using classes and functions.

I don't know why, but my function doesn't work. Although it recognizes my database, it's giving an error message when I submit the form.

What do I need to change?

Here's my form page code:

```
<?php
include("BDMySQL.class.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Registo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>   
</head>

<body>
    <span id="background"></span>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html">Apenas as melhores da <em>BlastingBeats Rec.</em></a>
            </div>

            <ul id="navigation">
            <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="registo.html">Registar</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul id="connect">
                <li><a href="http://facebook.com/freewebsitetemplates" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://twitter.com/fwtemplates" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="link-us"></a></li>
            </ul> 
            <div class="footer">
                &copy; Copyright &copy; 2011.<br/>
                <a href="index.html">Company name</a> all rights reserved.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contents">
        <ul class="images">




        <?php
if($_POST['Nome']=="") {
?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"><p>
        Nome de Utilizador:<p>
        <input type="text" name="Nome"></input><p>
        Palavra-Passe:<p>
        <input type="text" name="Pass"></input><p>
        <input type="submit" class="button"><p>
        </form>
        <?php
}
else {
?>

<?php
include("Cliente.class.php");

                            $Cliente = new Cliente();
                            if($Cliente->introduzirCliente($_REQUEST['Nome'], $_REQUEST['Pass'])) {
                                echo "Registo efectuado com sucesso !!!<br>";
                            } else {
                                echo "Problema encontado no Registo !!!<br>";
                                echo mysql_errno() . "\n";
                            }
                        $Cliente->endCliente();


}
?>


            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

My function code:

```
function introduzirCliente($Nome, $Pass) {


            $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('$Nome' , '$Pass')";
            if($this->bd->executarSQL($sql)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

Comment: If it's giving you an error message when you submit the form, could you include that in your question?

Comment: its giving me this error message: error 1136

Comment: You are missing some columns for your insert.

Comment: And what i need to change?

Comment: So it's just showing `error 1136`? Nothing else? No line numbers, no SQL, nothing?

Comment: yes, is just showing error 1136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have more than just two fields in the clientes database table. As such, you need to change the sql line from:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('$Nome' , '$Pass')";
```

to something like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (username, password) VALUES ('$Nome','$Pass')";
```

where you substitute in the correct field name for username and password.